# Creating a spherical mask from numpy array and getting array indices inside the sphere

Tags: python, numpy

Hi I have a sample data for x, y, z positions:

```
# x y z
-0.120932 -0.300053 -0.296206
-0.0978073 -0.304533 -0.291415
-0.097738 -0.299779 -0.28466
-0.118981 -0.293157 -0.292577
-0.105695 -0.263689 -0.303431
-0.0759291 -0.254051 -0.294597
-0.0637251 -0.293032 -0.306507
-0.083585 -0.290494 -0.311816
-0.0928098 -0.294645 -0.294957
```

I would like to create a sphere of 5 units and then apply the spherical mask to get position coordinates only within that sphere. I would also like to get the indices of the corresponding rows (coordinates) that fall within the sphere.

My code looks the following:

```
pos = 'data.txt'

x, y, z = np.loadtxt(pos, unpack =True)


h = len(x)
w = len(y)
l = len(z)
center = [-0.120932, -0.300053, -0.296206]
radius = 5.


# create circular mask 
def createCircularMask(h, w, l, center, radius):

    X, Y, Z = np.ogrid[:h, :w, :l]
        dist_from_center = np.sqrt((X - center[0])**2 + (Y-center[1])**2 + (Z-center[2]**2))

        mask = dist_from_center <= radius
        return mask

inside_x = x[createCircularMask]

print inside_x
print len(inside_x)
```

I am getting the folllowing error :

```
   File "density_map_test.py", line 41, in <module>
    inside_x = x[createCircularMask]
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Could you please clarify why I am getting this? and also How I get the indices too. Thanks in advance

Comment: You forgot to call your function: `x[createCircularMask]` tries to index the array with a function object. Instead you need the return value: `x[createCircularMask()]` (note the parentheses). For the indices you need `mask = createCircularMask(); mask.nonzero()`. This will give you the indices along each dimension for the points for which `mask` is `True`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to  **Andras Deak** answer
You have a typo in your function when you calculating distance For Z coordinate:

```py
dist_from_center = np.sqrt((X - center[0])**2 + (Y-center[1])**2 + (Z-center[2]**2))
```

fixed:

```py
dist_from_center = np.sqrt((X - center)**2 + (Y-center)**2 + (Z-center)**2)
```

for me it works fine